# Series expansion of $x$ in terms of $\sin(\frac{x}{n})$

Tags: fourier-series, uniform-convergence, periodic-functions, trigonometric-series

I am looking at expanding $y = x$ for $ 0 < x < \pi$ in terms of sine functions of the type $\sin(\frac{x}{n})$ where $n \in \mathbb N$. This looks a lot like the Fourier series but I could not use it as an inspiration to solve this problem. I am also interested in showing if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin(\frac{x}{n})$ converges uniformly to $x$.

Comment: Maybe you want to try showing your work so far on the problem?

Comment: From Taylor series we ought to have $1=\sum\frac{a_n}{n}$ and $0=\sum\frac{a_n}{n^k}$ for odd $k>1$.

Comment: @MathAndPhysics So far I have been trying Taylor series like runway44. This gives an infinite linear system that I do not know how to invert. It looks like the Vandermonde matrix but it is sufficiently different that I did not manage to invert it.

Comment: It looks like if you just use the first $n$ terms each time to solve the matrix, each individual $a_k$ tends to $0$, so that might not be the best way to do it.

Comment: This isn't very rigorous, but if you take the Mellin transform, you get that $2s\cdot\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}s\right)\Gamma(-1-s)\cdot \pi^s=\sum_n a_n n^s$. That agrees with the above comment by runway44 for negative odd $k$ (including $k=-1$ when you take the limit). This may or may not be true generally though (I'm not that familiar with Mellin transforms). I'd suggest looking at some other transforms (or using this one) and seeing what makes it easiest to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

For a given $n$, compute
$$\Phi_n=\int_0^\pi \Bigg[x-\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \sin \left(\frac{x}{k}\right)\Bigg]^2\, dx$$ which is simple since, expanding and computing, we have
$$\Phi_n=\frac{\pi ^3}{3}-2\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k k \left(k \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right)-\pi  \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)\right)+$$
$$\frac 14\sum_{k=1}^{n} a^2_k  \left(2 \pi -k \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi }{k}\right)\right)+$$ $$2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{l=k+1}^{n}a_k a_l \frac{k l \left(l \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{l}\right)-k \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{k}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{l}\right)\right)}{(k-l) (k+l)}$$

Since you want $\Phi_n$ to be minimum , write
$$\frac {\partial \Phi_n}{\partial a_1}=\frac {\partial \Phi_n}{\partial a_2}=\cdots=\frac {\partial \Phi_n}{\partial a_n}=0$$ which is just a linear system of $n$ equations. You will obtain exact expressions for the $a_k$'s.

I shall not write the results, but, to give a taste, $\Phi_3=1.028\times 10^{-7}$, $\Phi_4=3.411\times 10^{-12}$ and  $\Phi_5=3.371\times 10^{-19}$.

Comment: Thanks @Claude Leibovici. I am still stuck on the fact that $\sin(x/n)$ are not orthogonal, so I get a system but I don't know how to invert it.

Comment: @CLic. For sure, they are not orthogonal but using matrices, the $a_k$ are immediately obtained. The required integrals are so simple.

Comment: Ok, I see your point now @Claude Leibovici. This is indeed an interesting solution thanks. But it has the same drawback of the Taylor expansion approach in which every time we want to add a new term in the series, we need to invert a new matrix. The coefficients also tend to zero, so I was hoping to find a series for each coefficient that tend to zero as we add more terms.

Comment: @CLic. I partly disagree since we know *a priori* all required integrals.